# Angular pass new data from query into child component

Tags: angular

In Angular, have you ever passed data to child component when you get data from API ? I can't pass new data from query into child component.

Comment: Do you want to pass response from API to child component or pass data by route query ??

Comment: i want to pass response from API to child component  and i want to 
repeat request for new  response from API for update data state in  child component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by many ways. One of them is using `@Input()` decorator in your child component. Your child component have a property and parent component changes this property every time it receives api response.

**ChildComponent**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() testProp;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**ParentComponent**

in html

```
<app-child testProp="{{value}}"></app-child>
```

in .ts file

```
const albumsApiUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums`;
this.http.get(albumsApiUrl).subscribe((res: any) => {
this.value = res[this.count].title;
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-14j6gm?file=src/app/app.component.ts